# Color button background permanently when clicked, and without pressure effect?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, button

I built a button image (first image), but I manually added the neighboring text as plain text. I would like to make sure that clicking on the button (image or text) the background color of the button becomes permanent (second image).

[image]

I don't like the effect of pressing the button, I just want the background color of the button. Can I modify the button I created by merging image + text into a single selection? Or do you have to create the button in another way? If so, can you show me how? I found some buttons on the web, but they're not how I want them: I don't like that it looks like a button (I don't want the rectangular outline, I don't want the effect of pressing). How can I do?

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
root.title("xxxx")
root.geometry("1920x1080+0+0")
root.config(bg="#f0f0f0")
root.state("normal")

topbar=Frame(root, width=2200, height=43, background="#e10a0a")
topbar.place(x=0, y=0)
leftbar=Frame(root, width=250, height=1400, background="white")
leftbar.place(x=1, y=44)


button1= tk.PhotoImage(file="/image.png")
btn1 = tk.Button(root, image=button1, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,  bg="white", text="sdsdsd", foreground='green')
btn1.place(x=2, y=43)
text1 = Label(root, text="aaaaa", bg="white", foreground='black',  font='Verdana 12')
text1.place(x=70, y=58)


button2= tk.PhotoImage(file="/image.png")
btn2 = tk.Button(root, image=button2, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,  bg="white", text="sdsdsd", foreground='green')
btn2.place(x=2, y=100)
text2 = Label(root, text="bbbbbb", bg="white", foreground='black',  font='Verdana 12')
text2.place(x=70, y=120)
```

**UPDATE 1**
After using **compound**, I get this. I don't know if it's the best solution. I get closer, but I still don't have what I need. I would like to stretch the selection color to the end of the white rectangle, then I would like to permanently color the background of the button
[image]

**UPDATE 2**
By applying width = 224, I fix the button background color length problem, but the button is centered. Now there is space to his left, before it wasn't there. I would like it in the starting position on the left
[image]

Comment: You can have both text and image in a button, but you need to set the `compound` option: `btn1 = tk.Button(root, image=button1, text='aaaaa', compound='left', ...)`.

Comment: It sounds like just a little experimentation can answer your questions.

Comment: @acw1668 After using compounds, I get close, but I still don't have what I need. I placed the new image in an UPLOAD in the response. I would like to stretch the selection color to the end of the white rectangle, then I would like to permanently color the background of the button

Comment: @Bryan Oakley  Sure, but in my case it's not a question of experimentation. I don't know if the type of button (image + button) I'm using is the right type to get what I need. Can you help me please? (not to experiment, but to tell me the right type of button to get what I want, thanks). P.S: For example check the update of my question, I added the new screenshot

Comment: Just specify the `width` option for those buttons.  However I think you used wrong `parent` option for those buttons, should it be `leftbar` instead of `root`?

Comment: @acw1668 Using width I solve the selection background color problem, but I get another problem that I didn't have before. The button focuses and leaves the blank white space to its left. In this way (I uploaded the screenshot to imgbb.com, a safe and trusted site for uploading images): https://ibb.co/0QGpj1M . Is there a way to move everything to the left? (although initially it was on the left)

Comment: @acw1668  In case you can't open the link, I changed the question with an UPLOAD 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `image` and `text` in a button by setting `compound` option.

Also suggest to use `pack()` instead of `place()` for laying out the frames and buttons for your case.

And I think the `parent` of those buttons should be `leftbar` instead of `root`.

Below is the modified code:

```py
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("xxxx")
root.geometry("1920x1080+0+0")
root.config(bg="#f0f0f0")
root.state("normal")

topbar = tk.Frame(root, background="#e10a0a", height=43)
topbar.pack(fill='x') # use pack() instead of place()

leftbar = tk.Frame(root, width=250, background="white")
leftbar.pack(side='left', fill='y') # use pack() instead of place()
leftbar.pack_propagate(0) # disable size auto-adjustment

def clicked(btn):
    for w in leftbar.winfo_children():
        w['bg'] = 'white' if w is not btn else 'yellow'

button1 = tk.PhotoImage(file="/image.png")
btn1 = tk.Button(leftbar, image=button1, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,
                 bg="white", text="aaaaa", foreground='green', compound='left', anchor='w')
btn1.pack(fill='x') # use pack() instead of place()
btn1['command'] = lambda: clicked(btn1)

button2 = tk.PhotoImage(file="/image.png")
btn2 = tk.Button(leftbar, image=button2, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,
                 bg="white", text="bbbbb", foreground='green', compound='left', anchor='w')
btn2.pack(fill='x') # use pack() instead of place()
btn2['command'] = lambda: clicked(btn2)

root.mainloop()
```

---

The output:

[image]

Comment: Wauuu. You are very kind :) Yes, the parent of those buttons should be leftbar instead of root. A little question please. Both buttons remain colored. I tried to color the background of the second button when it is clicked. I entered btn2 ['command'] = lambda: btn2.config (bg = 'yellow'). When I first select btn1 and then btn2, both remain colored. How to make the background color of the previous button no longer selected disappear? So to have only one colored at a time. Thanks

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. You are very nice. I have rated your answer and set your answer as a solution to the question. If you can, could you also answer this question of mine please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69789261/problem-in-multiple-scraping-and-creating-a-database-record-it-doesnt-scrape-w. I'll vote for you there too. If you get bored and don't want to, I apologize for the inconvenience. Thanks